# How does one display the time portion in the devexpress xaf audittrail module's listview

Tags: c#, module, devexpress, audit-trail, xaf

Adding the following code to the business object

```
    private XPCollection<AuditDataItemPersistent> changeHistory;
    public XPCollection<AuditDataItemPersistent> ChangeHistory
    {
        get
        {
            if (changeHistory == null)
            {
                changeHistory = AuditedObjectWeakReference.GetAuditTrail(Session, this);
            }
            return changeHistory;
        }
    }
```

displays the BO's change history in a listview. However the "modified on" property only displays the date portion of the modified datetime. How does one display the date and time in the modified on column?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this via the model editor. For instance, in the XAF MainDemo, open MainDemo.Module.Web's Model Editor by right-clicking on *Model.DesignedDiffs.xml* in the Solution Explorer and selecting *View Designer* and navigate to

```
MainDemo
 - BOModel
   - DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl
     - AuditDataItemPersistent
       - OwnMembers
         - ModifiedOn
```

and change the DisplayFormat to `{0:G}`.

As with all things DevExpress, it's best to ask in the [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).